# Is there a way to import a sql dump from storage bucket into a GCP cloudsql database?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, import, terraform

I am trying to find a way to do an equivalent of this command but in Terraform using google or google-beta providers (>=4.0.0):

`gcloud sql import sql my-mysql-instance gs://sql-dump-bucket/sql-dump.sql --database=my-database`

So far I am able to generate the cloudsql instance, the database as well as bucket in terraform, but not a way to import the dump into the database.

Comment: Did you try this? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/import-export-sql#import_a_sql_dump_file_to Do you have errors? issues?

Comment: I am specifically trying to implement this with terraform as I have a way doing it via gcloud command.

Comment: Not sure it's supported in terraform...

Comment: I man, did you found any solution, I had the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using this resource but it can be used after creation of the instance.

```
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_source_representation_instance
```

You can use the dump_file_path to provide the path of the storage bucket path.

```
resource "google_sql_source_representation_instance" "instance" {
  name               = "my-instance"
  region             = "us-central1"
  database_version   = "MYSQL_8_0"
  host               = "10.20.30.40"
  port               = 3306
  username           = "some-user"
  password           = "password-for-the-user"
  dump_file_path     = "gs://sql-dump-bucket/sql-dump.sql"
}
```

I hope this works.